# Node.js Get data on MySQL and sorting newest data

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to get the data from MySQL using EJS. What I need is, to get the newest users to start at the top of the table but I don't know how to do it.
All I can do is just get oldest to newest

```
<% for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++ ){ %>
            <tr>
                <td> <%= users[i].username %> </td>
                <td> <%= users[i].first_name %> </td>
                <td> <%= users[i].last_name %> </td>
                <td> <%= users[i].email %> </td>
                <td> <%= users[i].type %> </td>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve here in sql query.

1. You need to have a field 'updated' in your user table.
2. sorted by 'updated' field

   `SELECT username, first_name, last_name, email, type, updated FROM users ORDER BY updated DESC`